# Strange function parameter - working ANSI-C Quicksort implementation - need explanation

Tags: parameters, ansi-c

I've written (copy/pasted to be honest) an ANSI-C implementation of QuickSort algorithm some time ago. Today I want to understand it... And I can't get how the marked line does not give an error.

*"rozmiar" means "size" of course, it's from Polish and I have no Notepad++ on current device*

```
void QuickSort (int tab[], int rozmiar)
{
    int i, j, p, t;
    if (rozmiar < 2) return;

    p = tab[rozmiar / 2];

    for (i = 0, j = rozmiar - 1;; i++, j--) 
    {
        while (tab[i] < p)
            i++;
        while (p < tab[j])
            j--;
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        t = tab[i];
        tab[i] = tab[j];
        tab[j] = t;
    }
    QuickSort(tab, i);
    >>>>QuickSort(tab + i, rozmiar - i);<<<<
}
```

Can someone expain me how does compiler understand array to integer addition as a first parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Array in C is basically pointer to that type (it's a bit more complicated, but this explanation is good enough for this example) - so `int tab[]` is basically handled quite similarly as `int* tab` - and integer + pointer (in any order) results in a pointer with address *n* (where *n* is said integer) elements of `sizeof(type)` after the pointer - so you're calling your function with array starting at *n*th position as a first argument - which is completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an array like,,

`int a[MAXIMUM] // MAXIMUM is acc. to your convenience ;`

it allocates contiguous a space of MAXIMUM size and creates an `int * a` that will point to that contiguous space.

And that is the reason, when you **pass an array** as parameter(but behind scene, you are **passing pointer**).

When you call `fun(a)` , at that time your whole array is not being copied but only pointer 'a' is being passed to function 'fun' as parameter.

And rest is just **array indexing**. I hope you must be knowing that `a[i] == *(a+i)`.